# Git mode in terminal

Tags: git

I use git on Mac. And for each command I write `git fetch|rebase|log|status....`. What I would like is to write `git` press Return and enter git mode, where I just write `log|fetch|rebase`. Is this possible?

Comment: http://defunkt.io/repl/

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/gitsh

Answer (score 4):

You can use [repl](http://defunkt.io/repl/), by Chris Wanstrath.

Install it with

```
brew install repl
```

(if you aren't yet using howbrew, I strongly suggest you to have a look to http://brew.sh)

Once repl is installed, you can simply run

```
repl git
```

and all the subsequent commands will be dispatched to git.

Comment: awesome answer! Thanks for posting this